# Solving problem without referring to three circle theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic in the annulus $1\leqslant|z|\leqslant 3$, and let
$\sup_{|z|=1} |f(z)|=4$
$\sup_{|z|=3} |f(z)|=324$

$\sup_{|z|=2} |f(z)|=V$

What is the largest possible value for V?

Determine if this upper bound can be obtained for some $f$. If not why not; If so find an $f$ for which the bound is obtained.

This is a past comp question. The ovious hint given by my professor was Three Circle Theorem. I am familier with that. I was wondering  if there a way of solving this problem using other tools.

Answer (score 3):

Apply the maximum principle to $f(z)/z^4$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate that?

Comment: @Deepak The function $g(z)=f(z)/z^4$ is holomorphic in the same annulus. It satisfies the maximum principle. Therefore, $\sup_{|z|=2} |g|\le \max(\sup_{|z|=1}|g|, \sup_{|z|=3}|g|)$. Both suprema on the right hand side are equal to $4$.