# Proving maximum inside concentric circles.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic on the whole plane except the origin. Assume that $\sup_{|z|=1}|f(z)| \leq 16$ and that $\sup_{|z|=4}|f(z)| \leq 1$. Prove that $\sup_{|z|=2}|f(z)| \leq 4$. Now, this looks a lot like Hadamard three-circle theorem to me, but I am not quite sure how to prove this theorem or even use it for this problem.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Indeed, that looks like a direct application of the [Hadamard three-circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_three-circle_theorem) to $f$ with the radii $r_1 = 1$, $r_2 = 2$, $r_3 = 4$. Can you explain what your problems in applying the theorem are?

Comment: @MartinR: I am just not sure how I would do this without using this theorem.

Comment: *Hint:* Apply the maximum modulus principle to $g(z) = z^a f(z)$, which a suitably chosen exponent $a$. – Or have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/268477/42969 for a quite similar question.

Comment: You want $|z|=1,$ not $|z=1|.$

Comment: @zhw. - Yes of course I apologize for the typos.

Comment: @MartinR - I think the best way to do this with the hint you gave is to consider $z^2 f(z)$ I believe.

Comment: @HrafnMagnus: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @zhw. - Thank you for your answer, it seems you deleted it but I was able to see it before you did. Just wanted to say thank you for taking the time to answer :).